# Can the expanded form of {don't/doesn't} be used as 'correct English'?

Tags: negation, contractions

I know it may not be very common, but I need to use it in its expanded form (i.e., **do not** and **does not**) for a formatting issue.

For example:

> X **does not** see any logic in your reasoning.

*X: is someone's name.*

I'm aware that such cases are used to add stress and focus on the negation part like:

> He **is not** going to change his mind as far as I can tell.

So, would it be correct to use it in that form (does not) and still be considered 'correct English'?

Comment: The first example would sound more natural (to my American ear) if "reason" were changed to "reasoning".

Comment: The second example would be more idiomatic if "believe" were changed to "can tell".

Comment: It's all correct English. The full version is used in formal writing, while contractions are more common in informal writing.

Comment: @Jasper _ Yes, I agree. They rather sound more natural with your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @JasonBassford _ I thought {don't/doesn't} make an exception as I didn't find them in my search. Thank you for the _answer_.

Comment: I changed the examples to be more idiomatic.  This focuses the examples on the issue you asked about.  If you would prefer to have the examples as you originally wrote them, feel free to revert the changes.

Comment: @JasonBassford -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper If I copied and pasted my comment into an answer, I would likely downvote it. I meant it as a comment, not an answer. (Somebody else is free to expand on it and turn it into a proper answer if they wish.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and valid English. Use of contractions is sometimes taught to show informality, and the expanded form may be preferred in formal contexts, but this will vary depending on geography, circumstance, and period in time.

Use of "does not" does not add any stress or focus to the negation when compared to "doesn't", however it permits emphasis to be placed on the word "not", whether in speech or writing, for example, "He does *not* have permission," would have a stronger emphasis on the negation than "He doesn't have permission."

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my misunderstanding of the expansion concept and correcting it, besides the actual answer.